# convert some of the columns to rows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in below format and would like to convert some of the columns to rows in python. I have multiple columns like (HY-3, HY-4). Couldn't figure out using transpose/pivot

```
Year  HY-1   HY-2  Total
2019  300    200     500
2018  250    220     470
2017  280    220     500
```

and would like to convert

```
Year Cycle values
2019  HY-1   300
2018  HY-1   250
2017  HY-1   280
2019  HY-2   200
2018  HY-2   220
2017  HY-2   220
```

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars='Year',var_name='Cycle',value_name='values')`

Comment: You can always do manipulations with `df.values`. For example, you can slice the column you are looking at (and add `.copy()` to the end), concatenate (`np.concatenate`), and re-assign it to the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.melt(id_vars = 'Year', var_name='Cycle', value_name='values')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this following code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":[2019, 2018, 2017],
                   "HY-1":[300, 250, 280],
                   "HY-2":[200, 220, 220]})

df = df.melt(id_vars = 'Year')
df.rename({'variable':'Cycle', 'value':'values'}, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```